# How to annotate a decorator on a generator using type hinting?

Tags: python, python-3.x, generator, type-hinting

I'm working with generators-as-coroutines as described in the excellent triplet of presentations by David Beazley (at http://www.dabeaz.com/coroutines/) and I can't figure out how to type the decorator `consumer`.  Here's what I have so far:

```
from typing import Any, Callable, Generator, Iterable

ArbGenerator = Generator[Any, Any, Any]

def consumer(fn: ❓) -> ❓:
    @wraps(fn)
    def start(*args: Any) -> ArbGenerator:
        c = fn(*args)
        c.send(None)
        return c
return start
```

Example of use, kind of abridged:

```
@consumer
def identity(target: ArbGenerator) -> ArbGenerator:
    while True:
        item = yield
        target.send(item)

@consumer
def logeach(label: Any, target: ArbGenerator) -> ArbGenerator:
    while True:
        item = yield
        print(label, item)
        target.send(item)

pipeline = identity(logeach("EXAMPLE", some_coroutine_sink()))
```

Bold `❓` marks where I'm unsure - and I'm also unsure about the type I defined `ArbGenerator`.  (Problem is, without the (decorator) function `consumer` itself typed, I'm not sure `mypy` is analyzing any generator function with that decorator so that's why I'm unsure about `ArbGenerator`.)

I'm interested in the tightest type, something better than `Any`, so that when I compose chains of these coroutines `mypy` will give me nice warnings if the chain isn't set up right.

(Python 3.5 if it matters.)

Comment: I tend to treat explicit typing as optional, and that seems to be the most generous application of typing in the Python community. In this case it seems that *any* typing is probably more painful for the (future) programmer than duck typing alone, so I would omit it.

Comment: @AdamSmith - TBH I thought that that (omitting explicit typing) was the pythonic philosophy - so I was somewhat surprised when at my new job (where I'm relatively new to Python) that type hints even existed and that my colleagues are using it heavily.

Comment: That's great news for you! I'm interested to see a good solution here, and since both strong explicit typing and coroutines are areas of weakness for me, I'm watching this question with bated breath :)

Comment: @davidbak Why don't you use `typing.Coroutine`?

Comment: @Kasrâmvd - Thank you. For some reason I thought `Coroutine` was specific to async.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a more specific way, here are few things you can do:

1. Use `Callable` type instead of question marks.
2. Use `typing.Coroutine` for `targets` and drop the `ArbGenerator`.
3. Coroutines return a generator and the return type could be a `Generator` or one of its supertypes

The reason that you should use callable instead of question marks is that `fn` is supposed to be a callable object at first and that's why you're wrapping it with a decorator. The `Coroutine` will be created after calling the object and the return type is/should be obviously a callable object as well.

```
from typing import Any, Callable,Generator, Coroutine
from functools import wraps


def consumer(fn: Callable) -> Callable:
    @wraps(fn)
    def start(*args: Any) -> Coroutine:
        c = fn(*args)  # type: Coroutine
        c.send(None)
        return c
    return start


@consumer
def identity(target: Coroutine) -> Generator:
    while True:
        item = yield
        target.send(item)

@consumer
def logeach(label: Any, target: Coroutine) -> Generator:
    while True:
        item = yield
        print(label, item)
        target.send(item)
```

*Note*: As it's also mentioned in documentation, if you want to use a more precise syntax for annotating the generator type you can use the following syntax:

```
Generator[YieldType, SendType, ReturnType]
```

Read more: https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Generator

Comment: For some reason I thought `Coroutine` was specific to async.  Now, I had been running `mypy --strict` but this solution almost works with `mypy --strict --allow-any-generics` to have the non-specific `Callable` and `Coroutine` and `Generator`: I edited it to hint `c` in the wrapped `start` inside of `consumer, needed to avoid an error at `return c` which was `Any` is not a `Coroutine`.

Comment: I guess I'm wondering why the return type from the coroutines isn't `Coroutine` since they clearly are (`yield` on RHS of assignment)?

Comment: @davidbak Because they don't return a `Coroutine`. In fact, they return `None` (Python abstraction for the absence of any object). However, if you want to make the generator's typing more precise you can use `Generator[YieldType, SendType, ReturnType]` syntax. Read more here https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Generator